# avc: denied { read } for name="usb" dev="tmpfs" ino=114668 in Flutter ( Android ) App

Tags: java, android, flutter, usb

I am developing an Flutter app that use Mantra Android Sdk, that needs to access a USB device connected to the device. However, when I run the app, I encounter the following error in Logcat:

`avc: denied { read } for name="usb" dev="tmpfs" ino=114668 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:usb_device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0`

I have already added the `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />` permission in my app's manifest file, but I still get this error.

How can I resolve this error and allow my app to access the USB device? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have added the

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my app's manifest file.

Comment: any solution? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77067946/get-the-list-of-files-in-dev-directory-in-android